# Detect Curve Corners

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to add cubes to the corners of my line and spheres to straight lines. How can I do this in blender geometry nodes?

[image: example of my target]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding objects on corners is easy - just use instance on points.

To set spheres on lines - convert line to mesh, split, then convert back to curve. Resample curve, first an last points have to be removed:

[image]

Comment: You are my hero, believe me, I did a lot of research before asking, thank you very much.